# auth0 jwt authentication Error parsing token: Token used before issued

Tags: reactjs, go, jwt, auth0, http-status-code-401

I have successfully setup authentication with Auth0 however when Auth0 redirects back to my callback, I then can't access ajax endpoints.

However, if I refresh the page (without going through authentication again), I now can. I can see in localStorage that the `access_token` has been set. So it seems odd that when I refresh the token is set but the first time its not.

I suspect I am loading components before localStorage is setup, and that means that the request to the api fails. However I'm not sure of the fix.

I get the error `Error parsing token: Token used before issued` and a 401 on the request to the api

My code is below:

Im using libraries

```
"github.com/auth0/go-jwt-middleware"
"github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go"
```

I initialise the verification of the token here:

```
func (h *Page) Init() error {
    h.JWTMiddleware = jwtmiddleware.New(jwtmiddleware.Options{
        ValidationKeyGetter: func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
            aud := os.Getenv("AUTH0_API_AUDIENCE")
            checkAudience := token.Claims.(jwt.MapClaims).VerifyAudience(aud, false)
            if !checkAudience {
                return token, errors.New("Invalid audience.")
            }
            // verify iss claim
            iss := os.Getenv("AUTH0_DOMAIN")
            fmt.Println("iss == ", iss)
            checkIss := token.Claims.(jwt.MapClaims).VerifyIssuer(iss, false)
            if !checkIss {
                return token, errors.New("Invalid issuer.")
            }

            cert, err := getPemCert(token)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("could not get cert: %+v", err)
                return cert, err
            }

            result, _ := jwt.ParseRSAPublicKeyFromPEM([]byte(cert))
            return result, nil
        },
        SigningMethod: jwt.SigningMethodRS256,
    })

    return nil
}
```

I configure the pem and my middleware here

```
func (h *Page) authMiddleware() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        // Get the client secret key
        err := h.JWTMiddleware.CheckJWT(c.Writer, c.Request)
        if err != nil {
            // Token not found
            fmt.Println("error checking jwt ", err)           <<<---- FAILS HERE!
            c.Abort()
            c.Writer.WriteHeader(http.StatusUnauthorized)
            c.Writer.Write([]byte("Unauthorized"))
            return
        }
    }
}

func getPemCert(token *jwt.Token) (string, error) {
    cert := ""
    resp, err := http.Get(os.Getenv("AUTH0_DOMAIN") + ".well-known/jwks.json")
    if err != nil {
        return cert, err
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    var jwks = Jwks{}
    err = json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&jwks)

    if err != nil {
        return cert, err
    }

    x5c := jwks.Keys[0].X5c
    for k, v := range x5c {
        if token.Header["kid"] == jwks.Keys[k].Kid {
            cert = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" + v + "\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----"
        }
    }
    if cert == "" {
        return cert, errors.New("unable to find appropriate key")
    }

    return cert, nil
}
```

and my react frontend is here

```
const AUTH0_CLIENT_ID = "xxx7vOQeStuKmaNfwxoWX"//'{{ $variables := index .Globals "jokish.so"}}{{index $variables "auth0-key"}}';
const AUTH0_DOMAIN = "xxx.eu.auth0.com"//'{{ $variables := index .Globals "jokish.so"}}{{index $variables "domain"}}';
const AUTH0_CALLBACK_URL = "http://localhost:9000/jokes/callback"//'{{ $variables := index .Globals "jokish.so"}}{{index $variables "callback"}}';
const AUTH0_API_AUDIENCE = "https://xxx.eu.auth0.com/api/v2/"//'{{ $variables := index .Globals "jokish.so"}}{{index $variables "audience"}}';

class App extends React.Component {
    parseHash() {
        this.auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({
            domain: AUTH0_DOMAIN,
            clientID: AUTH0_CLIENT_ID
        });
        this.auth0.parseHash(window.location.hash, (err, authResult) => {
            if (err) {
                return console.log(err);
            }
            if (
                authResult !== null &&
                authResult.accessToken !== null &&
                authResult.idToken !== null
            ) {
                localStorage.setItem("access_token", authResult.accessToken);
                localStorage.setItem("id_token", authResult.idToken);
                localStorage.setItem(
                    "profile",
                    JSON.stringify(authResult.idTokenPayload)
                );
                window.location = window.location.href.substr(
                    0,
                    window.location.href.indexOf("#")
                );
            }
        });
    }

    setup() {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            beforeSend: (r) => {
                console.log("setting ajax up with token ", localStorage.getItem("access_token"))
                if (localStorage.getItem("access_token")) {
                    r.setRequestHeader(
                        "Authorization",
                        "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("access_token")
                    );
                }
            }
        });
    }

    setState() {
        let idToken = localStorage.getItem("id_token");
        if (idToken) {
            this.loggedIn = true;
        } else {
            this.loggedIn = false;
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.setup();
        this.parseHash();
        this.setState();
    }

    render() {
        if (this.loggedIn) {
            return <LoggedIn />;
        }
        return <Home />;
    }
}

class Home extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.authenticate = this.authenticate.bind(this);
    }
    authenticate() {
        this.WebAuth = new auth0.WebAuth({
            domain: AUTH0_DOMAIN,
            clientID: AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
            scope: "openid profile",
            audience: AUTH0_API_AUDIENCE,
            responseType: "token id_token",
            redirectUri: AUTH0_CALLBACK_URL
        });
        this.WebAuth.authorize();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 jumbotron text-center">
                        <h1>Jokeish</h1>
                        <p>A load of Dad jokes XD</p>
                        <p>Sign in to get access </p>
                        <a
                            onClick={this.authenticate}
                            className="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-login btn-block"
                        >
                            Sign In
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class LoggedIn extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            jokes: []
        };

        this.serverRequest = this.serverRequest.bind(this);
        this.logout = this.logout.bind(this);
    }

    logout() {
        localStorage.removeItem("id_token");
        localStorage.removeItem("access_token");
        localStorage.removeItem("profile");
        location.reload();
    }

    serverRequest() {
        $.get("http://localhost:9000/jokes/api/jokes", res => {
            this.setState({
                jokes: res
            });
        });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.serverRequest();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <br />
                <span className="pull-right">
          <a onClick={this.logout}>Log out</a>
        </span>
                <h2>Jokeish</h2>
                <p>Let's feed you with some funny Jokes!!!</p>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="container">
                        {this.state.jokes.map(function(joke, i) {
                            return <Joke key={i} joke={joke} />;
                        })}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class Joke extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            liked: "",
            jokes: []
        };
        this.like = this.like.bind(this);
        this.serverRequest = this.serverRequest.bind(this);
    }

    like() {
        let joke = this.props.joke;
        this.serverRequest(joke);
    }
    serverRequest(joke) {
        $.post(
            "http://localhost:9000/jokes/api/jokes/like/" + joke.id,
            { like: 1 },
            res => {
                console.log("res... ", res);
                this.setState({ liked: "Liked!", jokes: res });
                this.props.jokes = res;
            }
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="col-xs-4">
                <div className="panel panel-default">
                    <div className="panel-heading">
                        #{this.props.joke.id}{" "}
                        <span className="pull-right">{this.state.liked}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div className="panel-body joke-hld">{this.props.joke.joke}</div>
                    <div className="panel-footer">
                        {this.props.joke.likes} Likes &nbsp;
                        <a onClick={this.like} className="btn btn-default">
                            <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" />
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the exact issue. seems like whenever I use milliseconds for Issued At or Expired at this problem happens but if I use seconds instead of milliseconds this issue goes away. let's check it with an example:
imagine here is your standard claim token:

Error Case:

```
var mySigningKey = []byte(config.SecretKey)
standardClaims := jwt.StandardClaims{
    Subject:   user.ID.String(),
    IssuedAt:  time.Now().UnixMilli(),
    ExpiresAt: time.Now().UnixMilli() + config.AccessTokenExp,
    Id:        uuid.New().String(),
}
token := jwt.NewWithClaims(jwt.SigningMethodHS256, standardClaims)

tokenString, err := token.SignedString(mySigningKey)
```

in the example above I got the error "Token used before issued"

Working case:

```
var mySigningKey = []byte(config.SecretKey)
standardClaims := jwt.StandardClaims{
    Subject:   user.ID.String(),
    IssuedAt:  time.Now().Unix(),
    ExpiresAt: time.Now().Unix() + config.AccessTokenExp,
    Id:        uuid.New().String(),
}
token := jwt.NewWithClaims(jwt.SigningMethodHS256, standardClaims)

tokenString, err := token.SignedString(mySigningKey)
```

so by changing the time from milliseconds to seconds I fixed the problem. hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem as well in an auth0 setup using the same JWT library.

It is a known problem due to `github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go` checking the `iat` (Issued At) JWT field and requiring it to be strictly less than `time.Now()`.

Thing is, in the real world the server's clock can drift (even with NTP running, and Windows is particularly prone to this) which can cause this check to fail.

If/when v4 of `jwt-go` is released it will not do the iat check anymore (as per the latest JWT standards), but until then the solution is to add some leeway in the check. This can be done with a custom implementation of `jwt.Claims`:

```golang
const issuedAtLeewaySecs = 1 

type MyClaims struct {
    jwt.StandardClaims
}

func (c *MyClaims) Valid() bool {
    c.StandardClaims.IssuedAt -= issuedAtLeewaySecs
    valid := c.StandardClaims.Valid()
    c.StandardClaims.IssuedAt += issuedAtLeewaySecs
    return valid
}
```

Now you need to use the `jwt.ParseWithClaims(token, &MyClaims{}, ...)` function instead of `jwt.Parse` to have your implementation of Claims be used.

Unfortunately for you, `go-jwt-middleware` doesn't give you that option and hides this call internally. The only thing to do aside from asking for them to release an update that fixes this is to vendor their module and make the relevant changes in [these lines](https://github.com/auth0/go-jwt-middleware/blob/1c6db3ceac5f4d28b35ee4b9949a3f80030aa6a3/jwtmiddleware.go#L204).

EDIT: Just saw that `go-jwt-middleware` will soon migrate away from `jwt-go` as it's unmaintained, which should hopefully solve these issues.